# Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Container'. The argument is null or empty

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am working on this official tutorial from MS Azure team on [Back up a virtual machine in Azure with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/quick-backup-vm-powershell). But while running runbook from [Start a backup job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/quick-backup-vm-powershell#start-a-backup-job) section, I get the error shown below. **Question**: What I may be missing here, and how the issue can be fixed?

Following lines runs fine:

```
PS C:\Users\myUserName> $vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName "rg-cs-ansible1" -Name "myRecoveryServicesVault"
>> $backupcontainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -Status "Registered" -FriendlyName "myVM" -VaultId $vault.ID
```

But when I run the following line, I get the error shown below.

```
PS C:\Users\myUserName> $item = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $backupcontainer -WorkloadType AzureVM -VaultId $vault.ID
```

**Error**

```
Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Container'. The argument is null or empty.
Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:2 char:16
+     -Container $backupcontainer `
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlet
   s.GetAzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, your commands work fine on my side. I can just reproduce your issue with a wrong VM name this command, even if your VM name is wrong, it will not give an error, but the `$backupcontainer` will be null, it will cause the error in the next command.

```
$backupcontainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -Status "Registered" -FriendlyName "myVM" -VaultId $vault.ID
```

[image]

So in your case, please make sure `myVM` is the correct VM name used for `-FriendlyName` parameter.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). The name of -FriendlyName parameter misled me. I thought you can give a Friendly name (like an alias) to your VM. But it actually is `the` real name of the VM you are creating a backup for.